# PHP MySQLi Finding an Unclosed Prepared Statement

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

The mySQLi bind_param method is throwing an error "Commands out of sync". I am guessing it is from a perpared statment that has not been properly closed. Is there any way to see the unclosed prepared statement through the connection, or should I get to digging?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this one :

> C.5.2.14. Commands out of sync If you get **Commands out of sync**; you
>   can't run this command now in your client code, you are calling client
>   functions in the wrong order.
>
> This can happen, **for example,** if you are using mysql_use_result() and
>   try to execute a new query before you have called mysql_free_result().
>   It can also happen if you try to execute two queries that return data
>   without calling mysql_use_result() or mysql_store_result() in between.

Reference : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commands-out-of-sync.html

Comment: I found the code that is causing the conflict, but still don't quite understand why. It is simple a query method call to a mysql stored procedure with a fetch_all method to pull an associative array. I am not sure why this would cause the bind_param function to not work. The bind_param function is being used in a session handler? Is the stored procedure locking the connection perhaps?